# vector calling in c++

Tags: c++, vector

I need your help for a program which has a function which return an array with 3 components and then I have to use the components, separately, of the array for some operations in main.  I want to do this with pointers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

double vec( double x, double y, double z)

{
   double v[3];
   v[0] = x;
   v[1] = y;
   v[2] = z;

 return v[2];
}

int main()
{
double a, b,c;

 double p;
 a =2; b = 3; c = 2;
 p = vec(a,b,c);
 cout << "vx =" <<p<<endl;
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: I see you use array of 3 element. Did you try to use std::vector?

Comment: Calling a user-defined type `vector` in C++ is probably not the best idea.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you explain more clearly?

Comment: `return v;` - that would be returning the address of an automatic variable that expires as soon as the function exits, leaving the caller with an invalid pointer. And fyi, `vector` is a *terrible* name for a function in a C++ program. Replace all `double` native arrays size-3 with [`std::array<double,3>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and pretty much all the problems in this code disappear. Not sure how that helps the *real* problem though.

Comment: I have a function which give a 3D vector and I need the components of this vector in main

Comment: Just taking a wild guess but it looks like you might want to define a **class** that has `x`, `y`, `z` member variables.

Comment: The program which I posted is just a scheme for my program.

Comment: @MIhaela No you don't have a "3D" "vector", you have a simple array of values. A "3D" array would be something like `double threedee[2][2][2];`. I.e. an array of arrays of arrays of values.

Comment: I don't want to complicate using a class, I want to use  pointers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple errors:

- The first is that you use `using namespace std;` and then have the symbol `vector`, forgetting about the `std::vector` class. That would lead to a name-clash if you ever included the `<vector>` header file (which can be done indirectly by other header files).
- The second is the missing semicolon, which the compiler should give you an error message about.
- Then you say that the function `vector` returns a single `double` value, but you try to return a pointer to a `double`. This type-mismatch should also cause the compiler to shout at you.
- And if you fix the return-type then you will return a pointer to local data, which will go out of scope once the function returns, and the pointer will no longer be valid.
- And you attempt to assign to the array `v` in the `main` function. But arrays can not be assigned to, only copied to.

There might be more problems but I got tired listing them.

Answer (score 0):

C arrays don't work like that and can't be locally returned since the return type is a pointer to the first element which will be destroyed after the return. What you probably want is a class/struct. You also don't want to be pulling the whole `std` namespace into the global namespace.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

struct Vector3
{
  Vector3() : x(0), y(0), z(0) {}
  Vector3(double x, double y, double z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}
  double x;
  double y;
  double z;
};

int main()
{
   double a, b, c;
   Vector3 v;

   a =2; b = 3; c = 2;
   v = Vector3{ a /*x*/, b /*y*/, c/*z*/};
   std::cout << "vx" << v.x << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than returning an array of numbers to represent a vector, have a class or struct represent the 3d vector. One possible implementation is:

```
struct Vector3d
{
    Vector3d(double x, double y, double z):x(x), y(y), z(z){}
    double x, y, z;
};
```

or

```
struct Vector3d
{
    Vector3d(double x, double y, double z){pos[0]=x;pos[1]=y;pos[2]=z;}
    double pos[3];
    double  operator[](int i) const {return pos[i];}
    double& operator[](int i) {return pos[i];}
};
```

You can perform operations by 'overloading operators', and can even make a universal Vector class by making a 'template class'.

Answer (score 0):

you can use loop to show data of array, and make output in function vec

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

vec(double x, double y, double z)
{
 double v[3];
 v[0] = x;
 v[1] = y;
 v[2] = z;
 for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    cout << "vx "<<v[i]<<" ";
}

int main()
{
  double a, b,c;

  a = 2; b = 3; c = 1;
  vec( a,b,c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;


void fun(vector<double> &, double );

int main()
 {
  vector<double> s(3);
  double a = 2;
  fun(s, a);
  cout<<s[0];


  }

 void fun(vector<double> & rS, double a)
 {a = 2;
  rS[0] = a + 3;
  rS[1] = 4;
  rS[2] = 5;
 }
```